# Existence of Star Cyclic Vector for $M_\phi$- Necessery and sufficient condition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $X$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. $M_\phi :L_2(\mu)\rightarrow L_2(\mu)$ for $\phi \in L_\infty  (\mu)$ is defined by $f \rightarrow \phi. f$. $f_0$ is called a star cyclic vector for $M_\phi$ if $L_2(\mu)=cl \{ A . f_0 :  A \in C^*(M_\phi)\} $.
Give a necessary and sufficient condition on $\phi$ for $M_\phi$ to have a cyclic vector.

I have reached at the following condition:

$f_0$ is a star cyclic vector for $M_\phi$ if and only if for all $f \in L_2(\mu)$ there is a polynomial net $p_\lambda$ such that $p_\lambda(\phi).f_0 \rightarrow f$.

Then I got this:

Assume $f_0$ is a star cyclic vector, then there does not exist two sets, $A,B\subset X$ s.t. $A \cap B= \phi $, $\mu(A),\mu(B)>0$ and $\phi(A)=\phi(B)$.

My question is: is it possible from here to conclude that $\phi$ is one one except on a  measure zero set? For what $X$ can we conclude that?

Comment: Do you realize you never defined $M_{\phi}$?

Comment: extremely sorry for that..  editing it..  @TrialAndError